# How to make paper of react-material-ui semitransparent

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

I would like to make semitransparent paper component of material ui.
Does anyone know that?

I tried as follows

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  paper: {
    pacity: 0.5,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    [theme.breakpoints.up(600 + theme.spacing(3) * 2)]: {
      marginTop: theme.spacing(6),
      marginBottom: theme.spacing(6),
      padding: theme.spacing(3),
    },
  },
}));
```

```
        <Paper className={classes.paper}></Paper>
```

I thought pacity is able to make components translucent.
However, the code above makes paper components all transparent.

Comment: I guess you meant `opacity` over `pacity`. Also you set `backgroundColor: 'transparent',` which makes the background complete transparent. I guess, it interferes with your desired result of `opacity`

Comment: I agree with @r3dst0rm.
fix the 'pacity' to 'opacity'. It should work.

Comment: Thanks! After modifying 'opacity', it works well. However , Every component became translucent. I would like only background to be translucent. How Can I fix it?